# Server Response: Data String is empty

Tags: php, android, web-services

I'm sending my data string from an Android app to a MySQL database but I get the response message from server saying `" Server Response data string is empty[true,null]"`. Data which I sent is present in my log file on server side (insert.php file) but not inserting in database.
Here is my Android code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("first_name", fname);
    obj.put("last_name", lname);
    obj.put("email", mail);
    obj.put("phone", dv);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Debug:Error 1", "json data error in contact create: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
Log.d("My String", "string result :[" + obj + "]" + obj.length());

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"contact\""+ lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(obj.toString());
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
// close streams
Log.e("Debug","File is written");
dos.flush();
dos.close();
}
catch (MalformedURLException ex)
{
    Log.e("Debug:Error 2", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    Log.e("Debug:Error 3", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
}
//------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
try {
    inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
    Log.d("inStream",""+inStream);
    String str;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(inStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    // while (( str = inStream.readLine())!=null)
    while (( str = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        response = str;
        Log.e("Response Msg","Server Response(Campaign_Create) "+ response);
    }
    inStream.close();
}
catch (IOException ioex){
    Log.e("Debug :Error 5", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
}
// return response;
}
```

php code..

```
    <?php
include_once '../dbconnect.php';
class contact{
public function post(){
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
error_log(date('Ymd H:i:s::').serialize($_POST)."\n",3,date('Ymd').".log");
echo exec("echo json: $json >> /tmp/check1.txt");
echo exec("echo obj: $obj >> /tmp/check1.txt");
if($obj != ""){
$id=$obj["contact_id"];
$last=$obj["last_name"];
$phone=$obj["phone"];
$email=$obj["email"];
echo exec("echo name: $name >> /tmp/check1.txt");
$result=mysql_query("insert into contact(contact_id,first_name,last_name ,phone,email)                  values('$id','$name','$last', '$phone')");
return $result;
}
else
{
echo "Data String is Empty.";
}
} //func
} //class
?>
```

Comment: `Im sending my data string from an Android app to a MySQL database`. No. Your app sends it to a php script. `Data which I sent is present in my log file on server side (insert.php file) but not inserting in database.`. Well then there is something wrong with the php code. You don't show your php file so we cannot help. `Log.e("Debug","File is written");` why are you calling some json text File?

Comment: php code is here. 'file is written' is just a message nothing else.

Comment: That is not a satisfying answer. Please answer more to the point. `I get the response message from server saying "file is written. Server Response data string is empty[true,null]"`. There is nothing in your php script that is echoing such a message. Please clarify.

Comment: File is written message in code is before lie dos.flush(); means data is successfully send from app to the php file. now the message i'm receiving file is not written is from my php file else condition which means empty data string.

Comment: "File is written" is what your Android client logs. Why are you saying that you receive it from the server?

Comment: Does the file on your server, /tmp/check1.txt, properly contain the data you sent?  If so, then the problem lies in your query and database schema, etc.  If the file doesn't contain what you sent, then it's either the sending method or the receiving parser that is at fault.

Comment: /tmp/check1.txt showing nothing. i am confused which part actually causing problem. because if i perform this operation from server side using a php form it works fine but sending data from android side... not working. but data is in log file which means sending method working correctly. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the above code didn't work so here is the new code which i implemented and is working.

```
String fname = firstName.getText().toString();
String lname = lastName.getText().toString();
String mail = email.getText().toString();
String dv = dropx.getSelectedItem().toString();

ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", fname));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name", lname));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mail));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", dv));

try
{
HttpClient httpclients = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpposts = new HttpPost(url);
httpposts.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse respons = httpclients.execute(httpposts);
HttpEntity entity = respons.getEntity();
isi = entity.getContent();
String msg = "Thank You for Signup.";
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.e("pass 11", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("Fail 11", e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and here is my contact.php code.

```
<?php
include_once '../dbconnect.php';
class contact{
public function post(){

$id=$_POST["first_name"];
$last=$_POST["last_name"];
$phone=$_POST ["phone"];
$email=$_POST ["email"];

$result=mysql_query("insert into contact(contact_id,first_name,last_name ,phone,email)
                     values('$id','$name','$last', '$phone')");
return $result;

} //func
} //class
?>
```